# Skip first splitting char in csv

Tags: c#, string, winforms

I have input csv file like this:

```
 |Name|Surname|Age|
 |ABCD|DCBA|11|
 |QAZ|WSX|23|
```

And when I am trying to upload csv file to my *datagridview* table, I have first column empty, because function is reading first `|` split char.

How to skip first split char in each line?

Part of code:

```
file.ReadLine();
string line = "";
try
{
    while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        string[] splitArray = line.Split('|');
        Listing.Add(new List(splitArray[0], splitArray[1], splitArray[2]));
        count++;
    }
}
catch
{
    MessageBox.Show("Nothing to do here...");
}
file.Close();
```

Comment: Avoid using `String.Split` to parse files because it breaks if a value contains a `|` character. Consider using a well-tested CSV library like https://www.nuget.org/packages/CsvHelper/

Comment: The String.Trim(char[]) method may help. You can specify an array of characters that should be trimmed from the start and end before doing the split.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.trim?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_String_Trim_System_Char___

Comment: @Dai I've added a CsvHelper example to my answer below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just ignore the first index, by using `splitArray[1]`, `splitArray[2]`, and `splitArray[3]` (Ignoring `splitArray[0]`):

```
file.ReadLine();
string line = "";
try
{
    while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        string[] splitArray = line.Split('|');
        Listing.Add(new List(splitArray[1], splitArray[2], splitArray[3]));
        count++;
    }
}
catch
{
    MessageBox.Show("Nothing to do here...");
}
file.Close();
```

As others have pointed out, why not use [`CsvHelper`](https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper)?

You can accomplish this with a pretty simple configuration:

```
public struct Listing
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}

using (var file = File.OpenText("test.txt"))
{
    using (var csv = new CsvHelper.CsvReader(file))
    {
        csv.Configuration.Delimiter = "|";
        var records = csv.GetRecords<Listing>().ToList();

        foreach (var record in records)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Name: {0}, Surname: {1}, Age: {2}", record.Name, record.Surname, record.Age);
        }
    }
}
```

Here you can see some sample output:

[image]

Comment: I'd avoid using ToList, to avoid unnecessary memory allocations and use Skip(1) and Take(n) to make the solution more flexible if the OP is required to to make some changes to the snippet.

Comment: Since the data is set from a file, I'd refactor your solution to use a struct instead, because the class has no behaviour and you're simply representing data in a file. The refactorings should make things a tad faster

Comment: @KevinAvignon I'm always a fan of classes as they're usually a lot more extendable, as he may want to add methods in the future such as a `FullName` property (But I've updated the code). As far as `.ToList()`, I'm aware that it will cause a full enumeration, and I'm only doing that because `Listings` was originally a list, and I'm not sure what his plan of use is. Why would I use `Skip(1)` or `Take(n)`?

Comment: in a LINQ expression, Skip shows that you don't one the first element in iteration, and Take will show you'd only need the next n elements in the iteration and that the rest isn't relevant to the current pipeline.

Comment: But we do want the first element in the iteration? I'm confused at where this is coming from. Are you trying to say for optimizations (ie. If we use `Skip(1)` it wont cause a needless allocation of a Listing struct, if I don't use `.ToList()`)?

Comment: @KevinAvignon `struct` in C# has different, value-type, semantics compared to `class`, which means `struct`s can be more expensive at runtime than `class` depending on the usage scenario, so I disagree with your advice. Also, `struct` can have methods, implement interfaces, and be mutable, and so on - so to say that "a struct doesn't have behaviour" is just incorrect.

Comment: @Dai for the given scenario, it has no behaviour, and just having a class for this dataset made no sense for me. I do know about the differences between class and struct. But in this case, I accept what you said

Comment: @FrankerZ I'm saying it could had been Listing.AddRange(splitArray.Skip(1).Take(3)) & and when iterating on records, you don't need to allocate memory before iterating on it, you can let records to be an IEnumerable

Comment: I 100% agree with you, and in most circumstances I would tend to go with you, but when using a `using() {}` block, if he breaks out of the loop (With maybe a return statement on a web API), the IEnumerable fails as the filestream has been closed. This leads most new users into a bit of trouble, so I tend to just just `.ToList()` things for easier access down the road (Although this definitely can be a memory hog/performance hit on larger data sets).

Comment: @FrankerZ your solution work. There are needed only to change index from 1...3 not from 0. I do not know why I did not checked earlier this :) :)  Thanks a lot.

Comment: I would strongly encourage you to look into the csvhelper @Frihu, as it's much better coding practices, and results in some cleaner code. (You should be creating structs/classes for this, and not just using an array)

Comment: @FrankerZ is this csvhelper will be more efficient than this walkaround? What with time of converting csv files, will be less?

Answer (score 1):

You could pass the optional second `StringSplitOptions` argument to `RemoveEmptyEntries`:

```
string[] splitArray = line.Split('|', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Comment: (Not the DV), but this can cause some issues if one of the fields actually contains an empty entry. (ie. `|ABCD||11|`)